# Can we overload operator++(int) to a pointer?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have seen all the postfix and prefix operator. But I never seen something like a pointer type.
Is it possible to use this functions and make it works?

```
A& operator++() //prefix
A operator++(int) //postfix
A* operator++(int) // is this possible?
```

Let's say if I want to increment an int in A* ptr.

```
A a;
A* ptr = a;
ptr++; //incrementing integer i in a
```

Comment: All pointers are built-in types. You cannot overload operators for built-in types.

Comment: so the only way to do is to dereference the pointer before overloading them? @FrançoisAndrieux

Comment: @GlenioAlsinTan I think your understanding of overloading and pointers is not correct. If your type A is a user defined type(class or struct) you can overload postfix and prefix increment operator in that class or struct and then dereference pointer of that class and use that operator

Comment: But you can not overload increment operator on pointer itself

Comment: You can create a custom type that behaves like a pointer (e.g. with overloaded `*` and `->` operators), except for a different behavior on the `++` operator. But this seems like a bad idea.

Comment: @GlenioAlsinTan If you have a `T* foo;` doing `foo++`  or `++foo` will *always* increment the pointer and you can't change that. If you want to change that, the closest thing you can do is make a new `class` that acts like a pointer and overload the operators there. This is what the standard library does with iterators.